# PHP curl unable to access other servers via VPN

Tags: php, apache2

I have a server connected to my company via OpenVPN and I am trying to retrieve JSON from another server using PHP's curl command.

Running the most stripped back version of the code in PHP's interactive mode from the command line (php -a), works fine:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'status.int.companyname.com');
curl_exec($ch);
{...expected json response after 2 seconds}
```

Howver when I run this from within Apache, the script will just hang.

Setting some timeouts and outputting the error

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
echo 'Error: '.curl_error($ch);
```

Gives the error as

```
Error: Resolving timed out after 10517 milliseconds
```

Initially I thought this was a DNS-related issue, but changing the URL to use the IP address or specifying the address to resolve to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, [ 'status.int.companyname.com:80:10.10.0.5']);
```

yeilded a connection error:

```
Error: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

My next thought was that Apache was using the wrong interface. The VPN is the default gateway, so works fine with everything else but I tried forcing it with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '10.33.0.105');
```

This made no difference. After reading around a few other posts, I tried adding the following in various combinations but it made no difference.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

file_get_contents has the same problem

I don't inderstand it. Curl on the command line works and PHP in interactive mode work fine. It just doesn't work when the PHP script is executed via Apache.

Other things I've tried:

- starting Apache after the VPN is connected
- setting Apache to only bind to IPv4

Resolv.conf contains one nameserver, which is the correct one for the company VPN

The differences between the CLI and Apache versions of php.ini are as expected:

```
-disable_functions =
+disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,

-expose_php = On
+expose_php = Off

-memory_limit = -1
+memory_limit = 128M
```

Has anyone seen this before? I've lost a few hours of my day on this now and it's driving me mad!
Thanks

Comment: have you tried curl's verbose mode ?  the trace may provide you insight as to what is happening.

Comment: Yep. It returns the same messages as I get from the curl_error function but unfortunately nothing in addition to that.

Comment: I have the same problem: occasionally, when using a VPN, PHP's curl is unable to connect to a host. Using CLI `curl https://host` works fine. Using PHP's curl on other hosts works fine. I thought maybe PHP cached an incorrect DNS response (e.g., when using wifi with a captive portal, all hostnames might resolve to an internal IP such as 172.16.0.1), however setting CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE to false doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, I think I solved my problem by setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`